# Wix Visual C++ Redistributables with Bootstrapper

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, redistributable

Hi can anyone tell me how to reference the `vcredist_x86.exe` file in a bootstrapper for my wix installer.

I have tried this:

```
<ItemGroup>
<BootstrapperFile Include="vcredist_86">
  <ProductName>Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables</ProductName>
</BootstrapperFile>
</ItemGroup>

 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
<GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="$(TargetFileName)" ApplicationName="Server Setup" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" ComponentsLocation="Relative" CopyComponents="True" OutputPath="$(OutputPath)" Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\" />
 </Target>
```

But my error is:

```
 warning MSB3155: Item 'vcredist_86' could not be located in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\'.
```

I think this line is the problem but i don't know the correct name to put in and cannot find it anywhere:

```
<BootstrapperFile Include="vcredist_86">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages and find the appropriate folder (for example: vcredist_x86). Then open the product.xml file and use whatever is listed as the ProductCode.

For example:

> ProductCode="Microsoft.Visual.C++.10.0.x86"